# Is it impossible to select a nondeterministic value of an array element in Promela?

Tags: spin, promela

Following is the Promela code that I am writing.

```
491     byte api1[5];
492     byte api2[5];
493     byte api3[5];
494     byte reftask1[5]
495     byte reftask2[5];
496     byte reftask3[5];
497     byte rid1[5];
498     byte rid2[5];
499     byte rid3[5];
500
501
502 proctype init_call(){
503     byte i1 = 0;
504     do
505     :: (i1 == 5) -> break
506     :: else ->
507         select ( api1[i1]: 2 .. 9);
508         select ( api2[i1] : 2 .. 9);
509         select ( api3[i1] : 2 .. 9);
510         select ( reftask1[i1] : 1 .. 3);
511         select( reftask2[i1] : 1 .. 3);
512         select ( reftask3[i1] : 1 .. 3);
513         select ( rid[i1] : 0 .. 1);
514         select ( rid[i1] : 0 .. 1);
515         select ( rid[i1] : 0 .. 1);
516         i1++;
517     od
518 }
```

But if I try to simulate the code, I get the error message as following,

> saw: '[', expected ':' spin: osek_sp2.pml:507, Error: expecting select
>   ( name : constant .. constant ) near 'select'

However, according to the syntax definition, I can't find any problem.

> SYNTAX
>   select '(' varref ':' expr '..' expr ')'
>
> varref    : name [ '[' any_expr ']' ] [ '.' varref ]

What is the reason of this error message?

Comment: It looks like spin's internal parser is implemented differently from the online specification. Are you using the latest version of Spin? I would get in touch with the authors.

Comment: I am not using the latest version. Now I am using 6.4.3 version. From the version it controls 'select' statement in preprocessor, not in grammar. And there is no update or new features of spinlex.c in later release logs.

Answer (score 2):

Patrick is right. I'd say that this is a bug. If you look into `spinlex.c`, you'll see that when it scans for `name` before `:` only alphanumeric characters are allowed:

```
scan_to(':', isalnum, name)
```

Anyway, `select` is just a shorthand for a sequence of assignments. So a work-around might be to write the assignments yourself, e.g.

```
api1[i1] = 2;
do
:: (api1[i1] < 9) -> api1[i1]++
:: break
od
```